# Default constructor in derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

i am going over my old exams to study for finals and have noticed some stuff I still do not understand.

```
class Shape
{
  private:
  int center_x, int center_y;
  public:
  Shape (int x, int y) : center_x(x), center_y(y); {} //constructor initializer
}
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
  private:
  int length, width;
  public:
  Rectangle(): //this is where i have trouble, I am supposed to fill in missing code here
  //but shape does not have a default constructor, what am i supposed to fill in here?
  Rectangle (int x, int y, int l, int w) : Shape(x,y);{length = l; width = w;}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Sorry, i was supposed to add definitions to the constructors given and when they gave me Rectangle(): , I did not know what to fill in after the colon.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/179910

Comment: Note that c++ a class declaration definition has to be followed by a semi-colon.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches. Either you call the base class construcor in the mem-initializer list of the default constructor with some default values as for example (I use zeroes as the default values):

```
Rectangle() : Shape( 0, 0 ), length( 0 ), width( 0 ) {}
```

Or you can delegate all the work from the default constructor to the constructor with parameters.

For example

```
Rectangle() : Rectangle( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) {}
```

Take into account that class definitions shall be ended with semicolon.:)

Comment: Second solution is only for c++11 isn't it?

Comment: Thank you sir, i would upvote, but i apparently i do not have enough rep

Comment: @jpo38  Yes, it is. And what year is now?:)

Comment: @ricefieldboy I have enough reputation so I will upvote your question.:)

Comment: One addition: third approach is _not_ to have a default constructor in `Rectangle`. Indeed, if you do not allow a shape to be constructed without parameters, why at all a `Rectangle` can be constructed without parameters?

Comment: @Petr It is a question to the professor who wrote this assignment.:)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the wrong question. You should be asking

> What should a default constructed `Rectangle` be?

Once you answer this question, one of the following will happen:

- It will become clear how to initialize the `Shape` base
- You will realize that `Rectangle` should not have a default constructor
- You will realize that something needs to be redesigned

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that no coordinates are defined for your default rectangle.  So it would be:

```
Rectangle(): Shape(x,y) , length(0), width(0) { }
```